# Unhandled exception. Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, opencv, blob, access-violation

I'm currently writing a BLOB detection algorithm. When I run it I get the error

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF70476CDA7 in blobdetector.exe: 0xC0000005:
>
> Access violation reading location 0x0000007BDDA0347D.

This is the part of the code where it breaks.

The debugger stops at the last line before the `if(val == 255)`

```
void connectivity(BlobBurnMat temp, size_t y, size_t x){
    uchar* ptr = (uchar*)temp.getTemp().data;
    size_t min_y = temp.getTemp().rows, min_x = temp.getTemp().cols, max_y = 0, max_x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        int kernel[4][2] = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, -1 }, { -1, 0 } };
        int temp_y = y + kernel[i][0];
        int temp_x = x + kernel[i][1];
        uchar val = ptr[temp.getTemp().step * temp_y + temp_x];  //breaks here

        if (val == 255) {
            temp.setValZero(x, y);
            x = temp_x;
            y = temp_y;

            if (temp_x > max_x) 
                max_x = temp_x;
            if(temp_x < min_x) 
                min_x = temp_x;
            if (temp_y > max_y) 
                max_y = temp_y;
            if (temp_y < min_y) 
                min_y = temp_y;

            int pass_x = ((max_x - min_x) / 2);
            int pass_y((max_y - min_y) / 2);

            setCoordinates(pass_x, pass_y);
            connectivity(temp, y, x);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of the code. The above `connectivity()` method is in the `BLOB` class.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include<stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class BlobBurnMat{
//Class used to store a copy of the source image where pixels get burned in BLOB finding.

    private:
        Mat temp;
    public:
        void initiate(Mat temp){
        this -> temp = temp;
        }
    Mat getTemp(){
        return temp;
    }
    void setValZero(int x, int y){
        temp.at<uchar>(y, x) = 0;
    }
};

class BLOB{
//BLOB class to store coordinates of the BLOBs before they are added to the vector-array-list-thingamajig

    private:
        int x, y;
    public:

    void setCoordinates(int x, int y){
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
    int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    void connectivity(BlobBurnMat temp){
        connectivity(temp, x, y);
    }

    void connectivity(BlobBurnMat temp, int y, int x){
        uchar* ptr = (uchar*)temp.getTemp().data;
        int min_y = temp.getTemp().rows, min_x = temp.getTemp().cols, max_y = 0, max_x = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            int kernel[4][2] = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, -1 }, { -1, 0 } };
            int temp_y = y + kernel[i][0];
            int temp_x = x + kernel[i][1];
            uchar val = ptr[temp.getTemp().step * temp_y + temp_x];

            if (val == 255) {
                temp.setValZero(x, y);
                x = temp_x;
                y = temp_y;

                if (temp_x > max_x) 
                    max_x = temp_x;
                if(temp_x < min_x) 
                    min_x = temp_x;
                if (temp_y > max_y) 
                    max_y = temp_y;
                if (temp_y < min_y) 
                    min_y = temp_y;

                int pass_x = ((max_x - min_x) / 2);
                int pass_y((max_y - min_y) / 2);

            setCoordinates(pass_x, pass_y);
            connectivity(temp, y, x);
            }
        }
    }
};

vector<Point2i> getBlobCoordinates(Mat src){
    BlobBurnMat *temp = new BlobBurnMat();
    temp->initiate(src.clone());

    vector<Point2i> blobCoordinates; //Vector holding all BLOB coordinates
    Point2i blobCoords; //Coordinates of a single BLOB

    //Go through the binary matrix looking for white pixels.
    for (size_t y = 0; y < src.rows; y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < src.cols; x++) {

            uchar* ptr = (uchar*)temp->getTemp().data;
            uchar val = ptr[temp->getTemp().step * y + x];

            if (val == 255){

                BLOB *blob = new BLOB();
                blob->setCoordinates(x, y);

                blob->connectivity(*temp);

                blobCoords.x = blob->getX();
                blobCoords.y = blob->getY();

                blobCoordinates.push_back(blobCoords); //add a new element to the vector.

            }
        }
    }
    return blobCoordinates;
}


int main(int, char){
    Mat src;
    String path = "C:/Users/Runagar/Desktop/segment.jpg";
    src = imread(path, 0);
    if (src.data && !src.empty()){
        imshow("blobie", src);
    }
    else cout << "You fucked up ";

    vector <Point2i> blobCoordinates = getBlobCoordinates(src);
    for (int k = 0; k < blobCoordinates.size(); k++)
        cout << blobCoordinates[k];

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When i == 2 and x == 0, temp_x == -1 so you read 1 byte before ptr outside the memory allocaded.

You have to handle the case when x == 0, y == 0, x == src.cols and y == src.rows.

Answer (score 0):

`Mat getTemp()` returns a *copy* of your Mat instance.

`uchar* ptr = (uchar*)temp.getTemp().data;` retrieves a pointer from a temporary Mat instance. This instance is then immediately deleted, and you're left with a pointer to (presumably) properly deleted data.

Try `Mat & getTemp()` instead.

Comment: like, `Mat & getTemp(){ return temp;}`? Because that sadly didn't help.